# No handler found error with a nested paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, paperclip, nested-attributes

I am developing a web application in which I need to use paperclip to upload a picture. In order to avoid the "No handler found for picture_name" error, I have always been using the form_for helper to create the file_field which contains the picture.

Now, I need to upload a picture but this picture is in a model inside another model with "accept_nested_attributes_for". To avoid the above error with a nested model, I need to use the fields_for helper from the initial form_for. However I need to create new instances of the nested model dynamically. For doing it, I have always requested the view of an empty instance of the nested model and appended it to the form. However, I can not use the form_for as a parameter in the html GET request, so if I avoid to use the fields_for, I have the "No handler found for picture_name" error again.

Is there another approach or possible solution for this requirements?. I have been surfing on Internet for hours and I can not find any possible solution.

This are the main files that I have use:

**app/models/how_to.rb** (parent model)

```
class HowTo
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Paperclip
  ...
  # Relations
  has_many   :transports
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :transports, allow_destroy: true
  ...
end
```

**app/models/transport.rb** (nested model)

```
class Transport
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Paperclip
  ...
  has_mongoid_attached_file :picture,
    default_url: '/pictures/template.jpg',
    styles: {large: ['640x160'], small: ['300x300>']}, size: { in: 0..3.megabytes },
    content_type: [ "image/jpg", "image/png", "image/bmp" ], storage: :filesystem,
    path: ':rails_root/public/pictures/:id/:style.:extension',
    url: '/pictures/:id/:style.:extension'

  validates_attachment_content_type :picture,
    :content_type => ["image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/png", "image/bmp"]
  ...
end
```

**app/controllers/transports_controller.rb**

```
class TransportsController < ApplicationController
  ...
  def new_transport_partial
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js {
        render partial: ".../transport", layout: false,
        locals: { transport: Transport.new, number: params[:number].to_i }
      }
    end
  end
  ...
end
```

**app/view/.../how_to.html.haml**

```
%div{ id: "how_to#{ how_to.id }" }
  = form_for how_to, url: how_to_path( how_to ), html: { method: :put } do |f|
    ...
    %a.add_transport_button.upload_button.green_button{ rel: how_to.id, href: '#' }
      %i.fa.fa-plus
      %span
        = "ADD..."

    - how_to.transports.each_with_index do |transport, index|
      %div
        &nbsp;
      = render 'transport', transport: transport, number: index, f: f

    = f.submit "Submit", class: 'submit_how_to', rel: how_to.id
    ...
```

**app/view/.../transport.html.haml**

```
%div.transport_partial{ rel: transport.id }
  - if transport.persisted?
    = hidden_field_tag :id, transport.id, name: 'how_to[transports_attributes][][id]'
  = hidden_field_tag :_destroy, transport ? transport.attributes['_destroy'] : false, 
    disabled: true, id: "transport_destroy_#{ transport.id }", name: 'how_to[transports_attributes][][_destroy]'
  = text_field_tag :title, transport.title, size: 20,
    id: "transport_title_#{ transport.id}", name: 'how_to[transports_attributes][][title]'
  = hidden_field_tag :number, value: number, id: "transport_number_#{ transport.id}", 
    name: 'how_to[transports_attributes][][number]'
  = image_tag transport.picture.url(:small), id: "original_picture_#{ transport.id }_#{ number }",
    class: 'transport_picture transport_preview_picture', rel: transport.id
  = image_tag nil, id: "preview_picture_#{ transport.id }_#{ number }",
    class: 'transport_picture transport_preview_picture', rel: transport.id
  = file_field_tag :picture, value: transport.picture.url, id: "selected_file_info_#{ transport.id }_#{ number }",
    class: 'selected_file_transport', size: '24', name: "how_to[transports_attributes][][picture]",
    multiple: true, transport_id: transport.id, rel: number,
    onchange: "readURLprofile(this, 'transport', '#{ transport.id }_#{ number }');", style: 'display:none'

  %input.upload_picture.transport_upload.transport_picture_upload{ type: "button",
    onclick: "$(this).parent().find('#selected_file_info_#{ transport.id }_#{ number }').trigger('click')",
    transport_id: transport.id, rel: number, value: "UPLOAD" }    
  %a.transport_remove.upload_button.red_button{ rel: transport.id, href: '#' }
    %i.fa.fa-times
    %span
      = "REMOVE"
```

Thanks in advance.

PD: Let me know if you need more code.

Comment: Woof! That's an ugly block of code. :)

Comment: I'm struggling with the same problem, though, so I'll let you know if I find a solution.

Comment: I need space so I have answered to you in an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After considering lots of procedures, I finally found a solution which is a little complex and dirty but it's the only way that works for my purposes.

As I said in the question, I have 3 models: **HowTo**, **Transport** and **Location**. HowTo is the parent of Transport and Transport is the parent of Location. Aso, HowTo accepts nested attributes for Transport and Transport accepts nested attributes for Location. Transport is the only model which has an image using Paperclip and I have problems using fields_for and "No handler found for picture_name" error.

In order to avoid these problems, I decided to use the [Remotipart](https://github.com/JangoSteve/remotipart) gem which allows you to submit a form without reloading the page using jQuery file uploads. By this way, I have a big form for the HowTo instance and different forms for the Transport instances, which are independent of the big form of the HowTo model. These forms of the Transport instances contain the nested attributes of the Location instances and use remotipart to submit then. In javascript I manually submit the different Transport forms and finally I continue with the big HowTo form.

PD: If you need the code, let me know and I will post it.

Comment: Cool, thanks for following up. I'll take a look at Remotipart and see if it fits the bill. Cheers.